# ¿Cómo desplegar los datos de un ForeignKey con ListView?

Tags: python, django

mi duda es, como mostrar los datos a través de una ListView por medio de una ForeignKey, yo estoy tratando de desplegar los resultados de esta manera, pero no aparece nada y me parece extraño que el context_object_name no sirva al momento de colocar el nombre en el template. No sé como puedo hacer que despliegue la información en el template ¿Me pueden ayudar?:

> ReporteGanancias/models.py

```
class ReporteGanancias(models.Model):

    mano_obra=models.ForeignKey(ManoObra, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    parte=models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)



    def __str__(self):
        #return f'{self.parte} {self.mano_obra} '
```

> inventory/models.py

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Ok', 'Ok'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    )
    dealer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    codigoInventory=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    invoiceNumber=models.IntegerField()
    descriptionInventory= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    quantityInventory=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    unitPriceInventory=models.IntegerField()
    minimumInventory=models.IntegerField()

    # invoice_number=models.IntegerField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=STATUS,default='Ok')
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)



    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.dealer}: {self.codigoInventory} {self.invoiceNumber} {self.descriptionInventory} ' \
               f'{self.quantityInventory} {self.unitPriceInventory}{self.minimumInventory}{self.status}{self.fecha_registro}'
```

> ReporteGanancias/views.py

```
class pendingStock(ListView):
    model=ReporteGanancias
    template_name = 'ReporteGanancias/reports-pending-stock.html'
    context_object_name='stocks'
    queryset=ReporteGanancias.objects.all()
```

> ReporteGanancias/reports-pending-stock.html'

```
{% for stock in stocks %}
<tr>
   <td>{{ stock.codigoInventory }}</td>
   <td>Part Name</td>
   <td>{{ stock.unitPriceInventory }}</td>
   <td><a href="#" class="stock-quantity" data-type="text" data-pk="1">{{ stock.quantityInventory }}</a></td>
   <td>{{ stock.dealer }}</td>
   <td>{{ stock.invoiceNumber }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor  %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como aceptas null en tu campo 'parte'

```
parte=models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Es necesario verificar primero en el template que exista la relación, posterior a esto ya puedes mostrar los campos si es que al relación existe.

La manera correcta de acceder a los datos de los ForeignKey es así:

```
{% for stock in stocks %}
    {% if stock.parte %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ stock.parte.codigoInventory }}</td>
       <td>Part Name</td>
       <td>{{ stock.parte.unitPriceInventory }}</td>
       <td><a href="#" class="stock-quantity" data-type="text" data-pk="1">{{ stock.parte.quantityInventory }}</a></td>
       <td>{{ stock.parte.dealer }}</td>
       <td>{{ stock.parte.invoiceNumber }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor  %}
```

Te completo la respuesta con tu ultimo comentario:

Te sale este error si quitas el null=True

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Esto se debe a que en tu on_delete lo tienes establecido como models.SET_NULL, esto significa que al borrar el objeto relacionado se establece el campo a NULL, el problema es que si le quitas el null=True entonces no permites el valor null. Si quieres usar on_delete=models.SET_NULL requieres forzosamente tener null=True, si no quieres aceptar el valor null entonces necesitas poner on_delete a un valor diferente como CASCADE, PROTECT ó RESTRINCT, puedes leer un poco de cada uno de estos posibles valores aquí: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Si esta respuesta te sirvió márcala como aceptada para futuras referencias.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, solo que al quitar on_delete=models.SET_NULL, me aparece : __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
 y al quitar null=True  on_delete=SET_NULL, but cannot be null.
        HINT: Set null=True,es decir que necesita ambos

Comment: Te edito la respuesta explicando por que pasa esto.

Comment: tienes razón, así es como se despliega la info, sigue sin aparecerme los datos quizá mi error viene de otro lado. Gracias por tu respuesta :D